# Getting 'sed: couldn't open temporary file' permission denied error in Docker script modification of host file system

Tags: docker, sed

I'm encountering a permission issue while trying to execute a script within a Docker container that modifies the host operating system's file system. Specifically, I'm getting a "sed: couldn't open a temporary file" error, as shown below:

```
sed -i 's[ ]root=[^ ]*/ root=${mender_kernel_root}/' work/rpi/cmdline.txt
sed: couldn't open temporary file work/rpi/sedqWUbSX: Permission denied
```

The problem exists only with `sed` command and its temporary files; other commands create/read/write/delete files in the `work` directory with no errors.

I suspect it's related to permissions, but I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Can anyone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and fix this "sed" command permission denied error when running the script in Docker? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Environment: Mac OS Sonoma as host OS, Docker Desktop 4.24.0, Docker Engine 24.0.6, container uses Ubuntu 20.04

P.S. Unfortunately, replacement of `sed` with other approaches is not an option for me. Switching to a different host OS would also be desirable to avoid.

Comment: A Docker container normally can't modify or even see the host filesystem at all, and one of the major reasons to use Docker is to prevent accidental modifications.  All Unix-like systems (including MacOS) include sed(1) already; can you run this script without Docker?  If that's not possible, how are you starting the container so that the host filesystem is accessible, and how are you configuring user IDs and other permission-related settings?

Comment: In my case script in docker should be executed in thew following way:

`docker run --rm  -v "$CONFIGS_DIRECTORY":/mender-convert/configs  -v "$INPUT_DIRECTORY":/mender-convert/input  -v "$LOGS_DIRECTORY":/mender-convert/logs  -v "$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY":/mender-convert/deploy  -v "$WORK_DIRECTORY":/mender-convert/work --privileged=true ...`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by VirtioFS, which is now enabled by default in Docker Desktop on Mac OS. Other options (gRPC FUSE and osxfs) work fine with `sid`

Answer (score 0):

I believe its permission problem since `sed` creates a temporary file. What You might like to try and check if it works or not:

instead of inplace editing with `sed` (`-i`), use `sed` and redirect it output to a temporary file, then `cat` temporary file into `work/rpi/cmdline.txt`

something like this:

```
sed 's[ ]root=[^ ]*/ root=${mender_kernel_root}/' work/rpi/cmdline.txt > /tmp/this

cat /tmp/this > work/rpi/cmdline.txt
```

do not redirect `sed` directly to `work/rpi/cmdline.txt` since redirects starts before executing the command and it will remove content in `work/rpi/cmdline.txt` before executing `sed`

Comment: I’m using a 3d party script, so I’m looking for a solution that will keep in intact (it is known that there are no issues if Ubuntu is used as a host os)

Comment: How do You want to fix something without any changes?

Comment: Changes on the host os side/docker configuration are ok

Answer (score -1):

You can change the permissions for read, write and execute using the chmod command in shell as:

```
sudo chmod +r work/rpi/cmdline.txt
```

And similarly for write permissions u can add +w in the above command:

```
sudo chmod +w work/rpi/cmdline.txt
```